# Add html code to a dynamically generated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js question that annoys me for the last couple of days.
i have a parallax template, where the parallax elements are generated automatically from js file.So i can add css style like transitions etc., but i would like to add some links on top of the divs, or some kind of on clik events.

What i think i have to look so far is in this fille (where the id of the divs are created):

```
enter //Parallax Element 2  
var item = {};
item.name = "#tree21";
item.stackOrder = 1;
item.content = "image";
item.image = "images/parallax/bg2.png";
item.sizes = {w:"350",h:"350"};
item.screenPos = ["40%","-100%","300%","-115%"];
item.visibility = ["true","true","true","true"];
item.parallaxScene = true;
item.bPos = 200;
item.mouseSpeed = 15;
```

`items.push(item)`;

and here (where i think the divs are generated

```
createScenes: function () {
        //Resize Parallax Elements if responsive
        if (responsive) {
            var screenProp = this.maxWidth / 1920;
        } else {
            var screenProp = 1;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (jQuery(items[i].name).length == 0) {
                jQuery("#parallax-container").append("<div id='" + items[i].name.substring(1, (items[i].name.length)) + "' class='parallaxItem'></div>");

            }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to your new div:

```
var div = jQuery("<div id='" 
                 + items[i].name.substring(1, (items[i].name.length))
                 + "' class='parallaxItem'></div>")
             .appendTo(jQuery("#parallax-container"));
jQuery(div).append('...');
```

Comment: Your answer is definitely better than what i've got so far. The only thing is when i put one of the generated id instead of  "#parallax-container" everything is messed up.

Comment: Can you post a sample on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: excuse me for the late reply... there are too many files (js and css) to add them all in jsfiddle.net. What i can do is to paste the link of the theme live preview. (i can for sure add a link with my own url, but i think that will be against stackoverflow rules ? )
The link is : http://themeforest.net/item/-horizillax-horizontal-parallax-html-template-/full_screen_preview/7879442

Comment: Seeing that doesn't really give any indication of what's wrong or how I or anyone else can help. I think it may be best to go back to the start and replace your question with something more specific including details about what's going wrong compared to your expected result.